# How to join table with condition available table

Tags: mysql

In mysql, I have some tables :

- a_202005
- a_202004
- a_202003

2020 = year, last 2 digits as month.

in those table, for example in table a_202005, fields are:

```
/*  date         total
    2020-05-01   100000
    2020-05-01   200000
    2020-05-02   150000
    ....
    .....
    2020-05-31   300000  */
```

the problem is, i want show something like this:

```
/* year    month  grand_total
       
// 2020    05     1500000
    
// 2020    04     2000000
     
// 2020    03     3500000   */
```

- year = available year in every table like 'a_'
- month = available month in every table like 'a_'
- grand_total=sum(total) in every table.

My query to get year and month available:

```
select mid(table_name,3,4) as year, right(table_name,2) as month
from information_schema.tables
where table_name like 'a_' 
order by year desc, month desc;
```

this is my query  to get total from every table:

```
select sum(total) as grand_total from a_202005
```

but I confuse how to get the table that I want, thanks before.

Comment: How did you arrive at this unfortunate situation? Why not revert to having one table, and a column for date.

Comment: You must use UNION of all tables enumerated explicitly.

Comment: @Strawberry OP has date column already. Agreed 100% with the rest.

Comment: If your tables are MyISAM you may create and use supertable using MERGE engine.

Comment: @Strawberry I cant make those become one table,  one table have million of rows, it would takes long time to get data from that table.